# Infinite series with recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to prove
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\tan^{2j-1} s}{2j-1}\underbrace{\int^{\infty}_{\tan s} \frac{1}{v^{2j-2}(1+v^2)}\,dv}_{:=P_j} = \frac{\pi}{2}s - \frac{1}{2}s^2,
$$
where $s\in(0,\pi/2)$.

I found out that $P_j$, $(j=1,2,\cdots)$ satisfies the following recurrence relation.
$$
P_1 = \pi/2 - s\\
P_{j+1} = -P_j+1/((2j-1)\tan^{2j-1}s)
$$

It is hard to proceed further. Are there any related theorems I can use to prove the statement?

**EDIT**

Using herb-steinberg's suggestion,
$$
LHS = \int_{\tan s}^\infty \frac{v}{1+v^2}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\tan s}{v}\right)\,dv\\
= \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^2s}{u(u^2+\tan^2 s)}\text{arctanh}(u)\,du\\
= \int_0^1 \left[\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{u^2+\tan^2 s}\right]\text{arctanh}(u)\,du\\
$$

Comment: Based on your result: Take $\mathcal S_j$ as the summand. Then $$\mathcal S_{j+1}=\frac{\tan^{2j-1} s}{2j-1}P_{j+1}=-\mathcal S_j+\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2}\implies\mathcal S_{j+1}+\mathcal S_j=\frac{1}{(2j+1)^2}$$ but this doesn't give what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Background step: Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2j-1}}{2j-1}$  Then $f'(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty x^{2j-2}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=arctanh(x)$.  This can vbe gotten directly from the power series for $arctanh(x)$.

Let $x=\frac{tan(s)}{v}$ leading to the original expression $=\int\limits_{tan(s)}^\infty \frac{log(\frac{v+tan(s)}{v-tan(s)})}{2(1+v^2)}vdv=\int\limits_{tan(s)}^\infty$$ \frac{arctanh(\frac{tan(s)}{v})}{1+v^2}vdv$

I'll leave the final step to you.  Use the $arctanh$ form and integrate by parts.

Comment: Can you explain more? Using arctanh was actually in my computation (which is not shown in the question), and the statement can out from the series expansion of arctanh since I was stuck at integrating arctanh directly.(I edited the question) @herb-steinberg

Comment: $\frac{d}{dv}(arctanh(u))=\frac{\frac{du}{dv}}{1-u^2}$  Here $u=\frac{tan(s)}{v}$  Integrating by parts gets rid of the $arctanh$.